# How to detect when a user is not online?

Tags: php, mysql, tracking

Well I've a admin dashboard which is PHP-Coded.
Now I want to know about my ONLINE users. For which I created a table in data base called "ONLINE". When a visitor/user comes to my site its IP is save on my database & on dashboard, show me **1 user online**.

The problem starts from here. I want that when a visitor/user leave my site (close the site, close the tab, and whole browser). This saved IP (in ONLINE table) of the user, migrate or transfer to another table in data base named "VISITORS".

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to send the data from one table to another, or that you don't know how to figure out if a user has left?

Comment: I know to transfer data from a table to another table but I don't know "how to figure out if a user left"

Comment: You can't do this by tracking IPs, you'll need a custom session handler that tracks explicitly terminated sessions and sessions that time out.

Comment: I think all you need to do is track the number of active sessions you have, and don't worry about storing IP addresses.

Comment: I have no signup and login feature in my site you can check @ http://www.mhk.me

Comment: @MHK you don't need a login or sign up feature to track sessions. IPs will not accurately track users and you will have no reasonable way to track when users stop using your site. I think the fundamental answer to this question is 'you should familiarize yourself with HTTP session handling and the PHP facilities for it'

Answer (score 2):

Detecting a user exit is a bit fuzzy. You can use javascript to send an exit notification to your server such as:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   ... insert your ajax code here ...
}
```

There are a lot of conditions where that won't fire though, so a better way is to use check-in code. You can make a php script that inserts/updates the ONLINE table(assumes the IP field on your table is set to be a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key, also requires you to create a TIMESTAMP field on the table - I named it last_check_in):

```
<?php
... connect to database ...
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ONLINE` SET `IP` = ?, `last_check_in` = NOW() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `last_check_in` = NOW()");
$statement->execute([$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]);
```

Then you can put an ajax call on a timer(here's jquery's ajax page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and you can use setTimeout in your callback to schedule the next update) to make the page check in.

Then you can change your query that shows online users to only show users who have checked in recently:

```
<YOUR QUERY> WHERE <your WHERE stuff> AND `last_checkin` > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

This would actually allow you to just use one table instead of two, but if you're set on using two tables, you can write another script that moves users who haven't checked in over and put that on a cron timer.

Comment: My mind was blowing from yesterday night ! I couldn't get that how to do it. If you can make me a script then I will thank full to you.

Answer (score 1):

So, to "figure out if a user left" you need to store some kind of last-activity-timestamp and determine a threshold time period for what you consider "active". This could be 30 minutes, or 15, or an hour; it's really up to you.

You can accomplish two goals with one task by [using MySQL to handle your sessions](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_MySQL-based_sessions). Whenever you create or update a session, you can also store the IP Address and the timestamp when the session is being updated. If the user logs out, `session_destroy()` will be called, which will call `destroy()` in your session handler, where you can "move" the IP to the table for non-logged-in users. Using a custom session handler gives you a straightforward place to put all of the logic.

Comment: for this to be a complete solution it needs to also track expiring sessions - the question specifically mentions users who simply close their browser.

Comment: There is a lot of merit to the threshold concept. Screw the perpetual session concept and nebulous exit. Those are voodoo. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use one table "VISITORS".
For Example, period is 1 hour.
Add field:

- *FirstActivityInHour* (DateTime, TimeStamp or Int (minutes part))
- *LastActivityInHour* (DateTime, TimeStamp or Int (minutes part))

If visitors leave site - you can not track this action, no action. You can track last action.

If *LastActivityInHour* near now moment - visitor online. Non-optimal query example (FirstActivityInHour, LastActivityInHour - DateTime):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM "Visitors"
WHERE
    LastActivityInHour > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
    AND
    DATE_ADD(FirstActivityInHour, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > NOW();
```